# SQL structure design

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating an app where I want to display the latest articles browsed by users.
What I had in mind is create a table, in which I create rows with userIDs and articleIDs. but this approach is way too simple and straightforward and may run into issues once the user base increases.

Is there a better way to do this? I am really sure there must be.

Comment: Latest articles viewed by date or latest article viewed by a particular user? How many latest articles? Please be more specific on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record which users viewed which articles, adding a table with `userID` and `articleID` works well. otherwise, adding `viewCount` and `lastViewDate` fields to the article table will suffice (with cookies to limit the increment to once per session). Either way, performance issues are negligible until things get absurdly massive.